# Are secured functions in C faster than unsecured ones or vice versa?

Tags: c, string, function, security, c++11

For example is swprintf vs swprintf_s or wcstombs vs wcstombs_s faster/slower ? We give it some more information, so I beleave it is faster, but than again, if something is more secure, there must be some kind of trade-off ?

Comment: You might want to read https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_s` suffixed i.e. the bounds checked functions are specified to behave in the same way as their non-checked versions, except that in addition, they are required to perform additional checks at runtime to guarantee that the preconditions are met. The non-checked versions instead are free to assume that the checks have already been made.

Usually, doing something takes more time than not doing it, so one would expect that it would be possible to implement the non-checked versions more efficiently, than the checked versions.

However, the difference may (but might not) be insignificant or nonexistent, for example if the implementation has chosen to perform the checks also in the "non-checked" version - which is not forbidden by the standard. Of course, in the cases where additional information is passed to the checked function, then the non-checked function can't necessarily preform all the checks that the checked function is required to do.

P.S. the bounds checked functions were introduced in the TR 24731-1 document. They are an *optional* part of C standard library since C11. You've tagged the question as C++ too, so should probably need to know that they are not part of any C++ standard - not even optionally.

Comment: That's arguably because, in C++, you should not be using any of these functions. You should be using `std::string` and/or streams instead.

Answer (score 2):

"Secure" only means better protection against buffer overrun. So it must have one or more counter(s) it maintains. When an implementation uses an identical code base for secure and non-secure functions, theoretically the secure versions must be slower as they maintain one or more additional counter(s).

However, the cpu usage thereto is negligable compared to the complexity of the base functions. In other words: don't bother about this; you can't even measure it.

Answer (score 0):

The standard makes no requirements for the relative speeds of the functions you mention.

There is no intrinsic reason why there should be a *measurable* difference between the `_s` suffixed versions and the plain ones, so the answer, as always, is, "it depends on the implementation".